# Set correct permission to folder with Plesk on Wordpress - CentOS 7

Tags: wordpress, centos, plesk

I have install Wordpress by extracting an archive with command line with root user on my Plesk dedicated server.
The result it i have an incorrect permission set to the folder.
I think root is owner on some folders.

This is a screen of my directory listing:

[Click here to see the image](https://i.imgur.com/UsXGBZe.png)

For example i cant install plugin with the admin panel, i have an incorrect permission folder.

What is the commands line, to set correctly the folder/user permission for my wordpress website ?

Thank u

I have try to chmod the folder but its doesnt work...

Comment: you need to use `chown` to set the owner of all directories and files to your plesk user (the username you use to login on plesk)

Answer (score 0):

These three steps are required:

1)

```
chmod 0750 /var/www/vhosts/<main domain>/<document root directory of domain>
```

Example:

```
chmod 0750 /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs
```

2. 

```
chown -R <subscriber>:psacln /var/www/vhosts/<main domain>/<document root directory of domain>
```

Example:

```
chown -R johndoe:psacln /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs
```

3. chown :psaserv /var/www/vhosts//

Example:

```
chown johndoe:psaserv /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs
```